# MPMoviePlayerController undeclared (first use in the function) message

Tags: iphone

I dont know why I am getting this message when I click have this code

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] iniWithContentURL: url];
```

Is there something, I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to import/include the movie player:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

Furthermore, the MediaPlayer.framework must be added to your "Frameworks" folder in the XCode project.
To add the framework, right-click on "Frameworks", then select the path on your system where this framework resides. On my system it is under the following path:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/MediaPlayer.framework

Comment: I just had that problem.  I feel stupid for not realizing.  But thanks for this answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are linking to MediaPlayer.framework in your Xcode project. That's where `MPMoviePlayerController` comes from and if you don't link to it, the linker won't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

*MediaPlayer.framework* must be added to your "Frameworks"  and `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` in your .h file